# Where can I find careful discussions of equilibrium?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

I want to know what physical equilibrium is precisely. I'd like to understand dynamical equilibrium vs. static equilibrium, and I'd like to understand approaches to understand non-equilibrium phenomena.
Is there a classic review work I might read to gather this understanding?

Comment: You may want to search Google and Wikipedia for thermodynamic equilibrium, what consists of mechanical,thermal, radiative and chemical equilibrium.

Comment: I'm looking for scholarly sources I can learn and cite. A modern take on Tolman would be good, or a statistical physics monograph with a strong focus on concepts, rather than calculations and models.